# Passing argument to \ifnum

Tags: macros, tex-core

`\ifnum` works fine it it's got two straight numbers.  However, when calculation is involved, I get bunch of `! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.` errors.  Is there any way to solve that problem?

```
\newcommand{\axes}[1]{
\ifnum\ifnum#1>180 1\else\ifnum#1>-180 0\else1\fi\fi =1
  blah;
\fi}

\axes{200}; % fine
\def\anga{20.5};
\axes{180+\anga}; % not fine
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't use arithmetic expression in TeX primitives. However, since modern TeX all support eTeX extensions, you can use `\numexpr` to do the calculation:

```
\newcommand\axes[1]{%
\ifnum\ifnum\numexpr#1\relax>180 1\else\ifnum\numexpr#1\relax>-180 0\else1\fi\fi =1
  blah;
\fi}

\axes{200}; % fine
\def\anga{20}
\axes{180+\anga}; % fine
```

---

If you use `pgf` or `tikz` to draw axis (why not?), you can use `pgfmath` for length arithmetic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} % or pgf

\begin{document}

\newcommand\axes[1]{%
  \pgfmathparse{
    ifthenelse(abs(#1) > 180, "out", "in")}%
  \pgfmathresult
}

\axes{200.3}; % out

\def\anga{-20.4}
\axes{180+\anga}; % in

\axes{-5.5}; % out

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, that did not solve the problem...

Comment: The code works for me (`\axes{200}` executes the `true` branch, as does `\axes{160+40}`, while `\axes{190-20}` does not). You'll need to be more specific than "did not solve the problem".

Comment: @jake Now I figured out.  The problem is that \anga is not integer, but real number...!  So I can't use ifnum for real numbers?

Comment: @Pygmalion No, you can't. You could have specified that at the beginning. I believe there's a solution by `\ifdim\dimexpr` but I'm not familiar with these things.

Comment: @LeoLiu Not directly relevant, but you don't need the `\relax` before `<`, as the `\numexpr` will be terminated 'safely' by the `<`.

Comment: @JosephWright: Thanks. I'll add a more modern solution using `pgfmath` or `l3fp` or `fp`.

Comment: @tohecz: For real numbers, we could use a dimension argument, but that's still not good.

Comment: Of course I use tikz, so \pgfmathparse solution is fine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

For floating points, there are approaches using `\dimexpr`, as tohecz says. However, for a truly general solution, I would use the LaTeX3 FPU

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \axes #1
  {
    \fp_compare:nNnT { abs (#1) } > { 180 }
      { blah ; }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\axes{200}; % fine
\def\anga{20.5}
\axes{180+\anga}; % fine
\end{document}
```